# Why is recommended to configure an Eclipse Java project with SWT like a project?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I have maybe dump question but it can't get it off my mind. I'm starting to learn SWT and wonder why it's recommended to use SWT like imported project in Eclipse as described in [eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_configure_an_Eclipse_Java_project_to_use_SWT%3F). Isn't it better to reference SWT like normal library and link a jar file in to your project?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommendation is to make it easier for the user to quickly configure an SWT library reference *correctly* with all the bells and whistles. If you take a look at the SWT distro, you will see a .classpath file that tells the SWT java project what is a library, where to find its source code and javadoc. Here is an exerpt:

```
<classpathentry exported="true" sourcepath="src.zip" kind="lib" path="swt.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute value="http://help.eclipse.org/stable/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/" name="javadoc_location"/>
        <attribute value="org.eclipse.swt" name="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.CLASSPATH_ATTR_LIBRARY_PATH_ENTRY"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

You can certainly do the equivalent reference straight from your own project.

Answer (score 3):

You are completely right. I wouldn't use the referenced SWT either, and believe it is just for PlugIn development, where the SWT version is tightly coupled with the IDE version. In our project we also have our own SWT version, because it is independant of the IDE.